# Use theme constants in plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, child-theme, constants

I'm creating a plugin version of the [Roots Theme](http://rootstheme.com) function additions - to make it a bit more portable, but have run into a snag.

Part of what Roots does is add `htaccess` rules based on the current theme information -- like so:

```
// only use clean urls if the theme isn't a child or an MU (Network) install
if (!is_multisite() && !is_child_theme() && get_option('permalink_structure')) {
  add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'roots_add_rewrites');
  add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'roots_add_h5bp_htaccess');
  if (!is_admin()) {
    $tags = array(
      'plugins_url',
      'bloginfo',
      'stylesheet_directory_uri',
      'template_directory_uri',
      'script_loader_src',
      'style_loader_src'
    );

    add_filters($tags, 'roots_clean_urls');
  }
}
```

So, it's basically checking to make sure that the current setup is not a multisite environment, not a child theme and that the permalink structure has been updated from the defaults. It seems like the `is_child_theme()` is not being called correctly, mainly because I get the following error on the frontend:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant TEMPLATEPATH - assumed 'TEMPLATEPATH' in /Users/studio/Sites/base_wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant STYLESHEETPATH - assumed 'STYLESHEETPATH' in /Users/studio/Sites/base_wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 17
```

So, from what I can gather, it's the `wp-includes/theme.php` file that is not included in plugin files (which makes senses).

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one, but am trying to figure out the cleanest way possible to add in those constants to the plugin itself -> should I just include that `theme.php` file? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Looks like I can use functions that are in `wp-includes/theme.php` (like `get_themes()`) so I know that's not the issue. hm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEMPLATEPATH` and `STYLESHEETPATH` [will be deprecated in the near future](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298). It is not safe to rely on these constants. Use `get_template_directory()` and `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead.
And wait until the `init` hook (or `after_setup_theme` before you use them to be sure all needed files are loaded.

Example for a plugin:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_50359_set_plugin_basics' );

function wpse_50359_set_plugin_basics()
{
    if ( is_child_theme() )
    {
        // do something awesome …
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @toscho - thanks for the response -- I think what I'm struggling to understand here is that I'm not actually using those constants anywhere -- it looks like `is_child_theme` references them --> is there a better/different way to check if the active theme is a child theme via a plugin? Thanks.

Comment: The function is okay, you just can not call it too early. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That leads me to another question about plugin functions in general - but I'll open up another question for that if I can't find it after some research. Thanks!

Comment: near future might be relative .. 
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298
`Opened 8 years ago
Last modified 20 months ago`